# One .htaccess file with rewrite rules for all domains

Tags: htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Our server is configured with multiple domains which reside in subfolders of the `public_html` folder.  So `domain1.com` is located in `/home/user/public_html/domain1.com` and `domain2.com` is located in `/home/user/public_html/domain2.com` and so on.

I've placed a *.htaccess* file in `/home/user/public_html` so I can put settings in it that apply to all domains.  I've added two things to this *.htaccess* file.  One is a special environment variable which is getting recognized by PHP just fine.  The other is a redirect for any folder called `.svn` to a file called non-existant.  So my *.htaccess* file looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule /\.svn /non-existant
SetEnv ENVIRONMENT PRODUCTION
```

The problem is that the rewrite rule isn't working at all.  The environment variable is, so I know this file is being processed by Apache, but the rewrite rule doesn't work.  I've tried several other rewrite rules and none of them seem to be working.

Do rewrite rules only work if they are in the document_root?

Answer (score 1):

You're not matching the .svn folder correctly:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule  ^(.*/)*\.svn/ /non-existant
```

I would actually redirect as a 403 Forbidden:

```
RewriteRule  ^(.*/)*\.svn/ /non-existant [F,L]
```

Comment: "redirect as a 403 Forbidden" - that bit doesn't quite make sense, you mean _serve_ a 403 Forbidden. There is no "redirect" as such. When specifying the `F`, the `RewriteRule` _substitution_ (ie. `/non-existent`) is ignored completely and Apache returns the 403 document.

Answer (score 0):

Apache only looks for `.htaccess` files within the document root.  It sounds like you have multiple document roots -- one for each domain.  The only place that you could put a central rewrite rule for all of them would be in Apache's `httpd.conf` file.

Comment: Apache will look all the way up to / if AllowOverride is set that way. See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/howto/htaccess.html

Comment: It sounds like they were expecting a .htaccess file outside the document root to take effect.

Comment: .htaccess files can exist above the document root. The fact the environemnt var was set proves it was being called.

Comment: Good point on the environment var.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a `.htaccess` files in a subdirectory (eg. `/public_html/domain2.com/.htaccess`) that contains mod_rewrite directives (even just `RewriteEngine`) then the mod_rewrite directives in your parent `.htaccess` file will be completely overridden and won't execute. This is the default behaviour. mod_rewrite directives are not inherited by default (in a *directory*/`.htaccess` context).

However, you can override this by explicitly stating `RewriteOptions inherit` (there are other options on Apache 2.4+) in the child `.htaccess` file. However, note that the parent mod_rewrite directives are literally copied in-place into the child `.htaccess` file (which naturally alters the directory-prefix - which *might* be a problem depending on the directive.).

On Apache 2.4+ you can inherit the other way ie. from parent to child, rather than child to parent (which is far more convenient in this case). So, in the *parent* `.htaccess` file (in `/public_html`), you can state:

```
RewriteOptions InheritDownBefore
```

Which will enable the parent mod_rewrite directives to be inherited by all child configs *and* it will execute *before* the child config.

Just to emphasise, this only relates to mod_rewrite. Other modules inherit by default. Each Apache module is processed independently.

Reference:
https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriteoptions